# backend:nodejs frontend:reactjs err: blocked by CORS policy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, cors, github-pages

I'm trying to build small app I put the frontend origin in the whitelist but still can not fetch data or login.
the backend I deployed it  on heruko and the frontend on gh-pages
before I deploy the frontend and the backend on the localhost everything was working of course by adding the localhost origin for the frontend to the whitelist

this is my cors.js code

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

const whitelist = ['FRONTEND_ORIGIN'];
var corsOptionsDelegate = (req, callback) => {
    var corsOptions;
    console.log(req.header('Origin'));
    if(whitelist.indexOf(req.header('Origin')) !== -1) {
        corsOptions = { origin: true };
    }
    else {
        corsOptions = { origin: false };
    }
    callback(null, corsOptions);
};

exports.cors = cors();
exports.corsWithOptions = cors(corsOptionsDelegate);
```

login code

```
export const loginUser = (creds) => (dispatch) => {

    return fetch(baseUrl + 'users/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 
            'Content-Type':'application/json' 
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(creds)
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response;
        } else {
            var error = new Error('Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
            error.response = response;
            throw error;
        }
        },
        error => {
            throw error;
        })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        if (response.success) {
           ........
        }
        else {
            var error = new Error('Error ' + response.status);
            error.response = response;
            throw error;
        }
    })
    .catch(error => dispatch(loginError(error.message)))
};
```

login user router

```
var express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var User = require('../models/user');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var authenticate = require('../authenticate');
const cors = require('./cors');

router.use(bodyParser.json());

router.options('*', cors.corsWithOptions, (req, res) =>{res.sendStatus(200);})


router.post('/login', cors.corsWithOptions, (req, res, next) => {

  passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
    if (err)
      return next(err);

    if (!user) {
      res.statusCode = 401;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.json({success: false, status: 'Login Unsuccessful!', err: info});
    }
    req.logIn(user, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        res.statusCode = 401;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.json({success: false, status: 'Login Unsuccessful!', err: 'Could not log in user!'});          
      }

      var token = authenticate.getToken({_id: req.user._id});
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.json({success: true, status: 'Login Successful!', token: token, userId: req.user._id, firstname: req.user.firstname, lastname: req.user.lastname, image: req.user.image});
    }); 
  }) (req, res, next);
});

............

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score -1):

1.Open your Chrome Browser and Search chrome web store
2.Search the Extension called " Access Control Allow Origin "
3.Install it in your browser and head to the options page of that extension
4.Over the TextBox Type your localhost address in which backend is running,something like this "https://localhost:yourportnumber"

Answer (score -2):

Bro, I am not sure that my solution will help you or not but I face the same issue.So I solved it using chrome extension with name "Moesif Origin & CORS Changer".Install it in your chrome extension and then try to fetch the data.